# Reduce space after title in two-column article

Tags: spacing, titles, two-column

I have a standard article in two-column format without author or date, only a title. I would like to reduce the vertical space after the title.

I tried using `\vspace*{-1cm}` after `\maketitle`, but the problem is that this only reduces the space above the left column, not above the right column.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Awesome title}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\vspace*{-1cm}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This only adds a negative space before the left column, but not before the right column:

[image: Left column is higher than right column]

Comment: Not very elegant, but you can place `\vspace*{-1cm}` inside the title (`\title{Ordinary title\vspace*{-1cm}}`), or in the date (`\date{\today\vspace*{-1cm}}`).

Comment: Actually, this would have been  elegant enough for me, but it does not work as I expected. It lowers the title instead of raising the text. I ended up redefining `\@maketitle`, as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spaces are defined in the `\@maketitle` macro. You should patch or redefine this macro to change these spaces. For instance, add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
    \newpage\null\vskip2em%
    \begin{center}%
        \let\footnote\thanks{\LARGE\@title\par}%
        \vskip1.5em{\large\lineskip.5em\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author\end{tabular}\par }%
        \vskip 1em{\large \@date }%
    \end{center}%
    \par}
\makeatother
```